# Find and replace multiple words in Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I really hope you guys can help, I feel like I've been struggling with what should be (and probably is) a really simple problem. I've written an app which creates a folder structure, copies in the relevant test documents based on user inputs, and populates the document header and test sheets with various variables. I have populated the template test documents with placeholders, ("replCustNo","replPrjNo","replCustRef" etc), some in the header, some in the body of the document. I can only seem to replace one word at a time, I can't find a way of listing all the references to find, then listing all the replacement variables. Seems like a very clumsy way of coding to have the find/replace over and over, or call on a sub for it.

Forgive me if this is really basic, I'm very new to coding, I'd really appreciate some help! I'm using vb and office 365

```
 Dim objWordApp As New Word.Application
    'Open an existing document.  
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open(projFolder & "SAT\2 HV Tests\Flash.doc")

    objWordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Select()
    objWordApp.Selection.WholeStory()
    With objWordApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "replPrjNo"
        .Replacement.Text = RefNo
        .Forward = True
    End With
    objWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

    'Save and close the document  
    objDoc.Save()
    objDoc.Close()
    objDoc = Nothing
    objWordApp.Quit()
    objWordApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be with document variables. 
Select a placeholder in the template document and then `Insert tab > Quick Parts > Field... > DocVariable > New name: replPrjNo`

Then in the code:

```
objDoc.Variables("replPrjNo").Value = RefNo
objDoc.Fields.Update
```

Other solutions can be bookmarks, custom document properties, Mail Merge, or some of the controls in the Developer tab.

Comment: That's a superb solution, very clean! although I've tried a quick test app, and for some reason the header and footer don't update the fields properly? I've tried {objDoc.Fields.Update} after each variable change... Word is registering the variable, if i open word manually and right click to update field, it does change to the correct value, but not until I do. What am I missing?

Comment: @phil if the fields are not updating when you save the document, then try `objDoc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).Fields.Update`

Comment: That's absolutely it, Thank you so much!