# Is it possible to create new document from template and automate its filling using visual basic form

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I want to make a .dotm template, from which documents base is constructed. Then I want to fill it using Visual Basic forms.

First I tried to do it using AutoExec and AutoOpen, but it didn't work out. So I googled, and found a solution - I need to use Document_New procedure. So right now it all looks like that:

I have a dotm template. In templates project I have a macro defined for ThisDocument and the form named **InputForm**. Macro looks like this

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    InputForm.Show
End Sub
```

In **InputForm** code I get some text from TextBox elements, and want to assign it to certain fields in newly created document.

Problem is the document is constructed from the template before I fill in form, so all changes, which should be done in new document, are done in the template.

Edit: Code for **InputForm**

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

    If IsRight Then
      ThisDocument.txt_Num.Value = txt_Num1.Value

      ThisDocument.txt_Date.Value = txt_Date1.Value

      ThisDocument.lbl_Num_Date.Caption = " ТКП № " & txt_Num1.Value & " от " & _
      txt_Date1.Value & "г."

      ThisDocument.txt_Project.Value = txt_Project1.Value

      ThisDocument.lbl_Project.Caption = txt_Project1.Value

      ThisDocument.txt_Author.Value = txt_Author1.Value

      ThisDocument.txt_Org.Value = txt_Org1.Value

      ThisDocument.lbl_Organization.Caption = txt_Org1.Value

      ThisDocument.txt_Phone.Value = txt_Phone1.Value

      ThisDocument.txt_Mail.Value = txt_Mail1.Value

      InputForm.Hide
   Else
      MsgBox ("Неверно")
   End If
End Sub

Public Function IsRight() As Boolean
   If IsDate(txt_Date1.Value) Then
      IsRight = True
   Else
      IsRight = False
   End If
End Function

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
   InputForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ActiveDocument` instead of `ThisDocument`.

You can try something like

```
ActiveDocument.txt_Num.Value = txt_Num1.Value
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194846.aspx

Also, check my answer here for easier alternatives [Find and replace multiple words in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752379/find-and-replace-multiple-words-in-word/37753875#37753875)

Comment: Just tried it, no luck. It looks like Shapes collection is empty(size = 0). But ActiveDocument is really the document that was just created.

Comment: Then maybe in the `ActiveDocument.ContentControls` or the `ActiveDocument.Controls` collection?

Comment: ContentControls is also empty. I am thinking about Fields collection, but it doesn't allow to use anything but index as argument...

Comment: I don't have Word at home so I am just guessing. My other suggestions are the `.InlineShapes` or maybe `.TextBoxes`. Also, you can try `MsgBox TypeName(ThisDocument.txt_Num)` to see if that gives any hints.

Comment: Actually you were right. I just used ActiveDocument instead of ThisDocument and it worked. It appears you can get fields directly using their names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the macro working to fill in the form once a new instance of the document is open I would try the following `Documents.Add Template:="C:/put absolute file path here, NewTemplate:= False, DocumentType:= 0'.`It seems to me your code is opening the actual template and not a " new document".

I would then attach this macro to a keyboard shortcut or trigger it off a button within the template and then run your macro to fill in the document. In my experience (which is limited) making macros as compartmentalized as possible provides me with the best results.

Comment: In fact my code doesn't open anything. It is triggered, when new document is opened. And new document is opened when template is opened. So chain of event looks like 

Open template => New document created from template => My form opens for template

Comment: Would you be able to supply the code in full. This might help get a clear picture of what is going on and zero in on the problem.

Comment: I added it to the question, thanks for trying to help :)